# Multiple hasMany associations with CakePHP model via column aliases

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model-associations

I'm making a little app for my softball team. I want to set up the following associations:

Model `Game` has two columns, `away_id`, `home_id`, both of which are aliases to `Team.id`.

In `Game` model I have:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Home' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'home_id', // also tried simply 'id'
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Away' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'away_id', // also tried simply 'id'
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

In `Team` model I have:

```
public $virtualFields = ['home_id' => 'Team.id', 'away_id' => 'Team.id'];
```

And:

```
/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Game' => array(
                    'className' => 'Game',
                    'foreignKey' => 'home_id',
                    'dependent' => false,
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => '',
                    'limit' => '',
                    'offset' => '',
                    'exclusive' => '',
                    'finderQuery' => '',
                    'counterQuery' => ''
                ),


// also tried only one 'Game' association with foreignKey => [home_id, away_id]
        'Game' => array(
                    'className' => 'Game',
                    'foreignKey' => 'away_id',
                    'dependent' => false,
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => '',
                    'limit' => '',
                    'offset' => '',
                    'exclusive' => '',
                    'finderQuery' => '',
                    'counterQuery' => ''
                )
    );
```

Getting the following error:

*Note: "Psychouts" is the only non-self-explanatory appearance in the SQL below; it's the database name (and also my team name, henh).*

`Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Team.id' in 'field list'`

SQL Query: SELECT `Game`.`id`, `Game`.`when`, `Game`.`cancelled`, `Game`.`field`, `Game`.`home_id`, `Game`.`away_id`, `Game`.`score_us`, `Game`.`score_them`, `Home`.`id`, `Home`.`captain_id`, `Home`.`name`, `Home`.`wins`, `Home`.`losses`, `Home`.`ties`, `Home`.`scored`, `Home`.`allowed`, (`Team`.`id`) AS `Home__home_id`, (`Team`.`id`) AS `Home__away_id`, `Away`.`id`, `Away`.`captain_id`, `Away`.`name`, `Away`.`wins`, `Away`.`losses`, `Away`.`ties`, `Away`.`scored`, `Away`.`allowed`, (`Team`.`id`) AS `Away__home_id`, (`Team`.`id`) AS `Away__away_id` FROM `psychouts`.`games` AS `Game` LEFT JOIN `psychouts`.`teams` AS `Home` ON (`Game`.`home_id` = `Home`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `psychouts`.`teams` AS `Away` ON (`Game`.`away_id` = `Away`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20

Comment: This is your problem `public $virtualFields = ['home_id' => 'Team.id', 'away_id' => 'Team.id'];` - That's definining virtual fields to (aliased) tables that don't exist in the query. If you remove any hacks you may have (including the above virtualFields), it should just work. You can if you need define a Team->hasMany->Game association by defining `foreignKey`false and add `conditions => ['OR' => ['Game.home_id = Team.id', 'Game.away_id = Team.id']]` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following AD7six's comments, the solution which, after testing, seems correct is:

In `Team` model, erase the virtual fields I'd proposed and then define `Game` association as follows:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Game' => array(
            'className' => 'Game',
            'foreignKey' => ['OR' => ['Game.home_id = Team.id', 'Game.away_id = Team.id']]
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
```

And in `Game` model, define `Team` association as usual:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Team' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
```

Comment: The above `$belongsTo` array is defining **only one association** - because the second `Team` array key will simply overwrite the first.